# Does new[] initialise an array of builtins?

Tags: c++, initialization, new-operator, built-in-types

Does using `new[]` in C++ initialise the allocated array to all zeroes?

Comment: No you have to do it yourself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does new[] initialise an array of builtins?

It depends:

```
int* = new int[42];   // default initialization: elements not initialized

int* = new int[42](); // value initialization: elements are zero initialized
```

Note the terminology: in the first example, the elements are said to be *default-initialized*, which for built-ins means no initialization is performed. In the second example, the elements are *value-initialized*, which for built-ins means zero-initialization.